# Looking to do a search for blog posts on wordpress where user can search for a keyword, year, or month or any combination of the three, getting 404

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a blog page that has all the blog posts listed but I have set up a search form that takes the params of the page.

```
 $query = array(
              'posts_per_page'  => 99,
              's' => $_REQUEST[ 'search' ] ? $_REQUEST[ 'search' ] : '',
              'post_type'     => 'post',
              'category_name' => 'blog',
              'order'   => 'DESC'
            );

            $date_query = array([]);
              


            if($_GET[ 'yearnum' ] OR $_GET[ 'monthnum' ]) {

              
                $date_query[0]['year'] = $_GET[ 'yearnum' ] ? $_GET[ 'yearnum' ] : false;
              

              
                $date_query[0]['monthnum'] = $_GET[ 'monthnum' ] ? $_GET[ 'monthnum' ] : false ;
              


               $query['date_query'] = $date_query;
            }

            $posts = get_posts($query);


            ?>
```

Here is my form where I use arrays to create the months and years.

```
 <form role="search" method="get" class="search_form_custom flex  items-center  " action="<?php echo home_url( '/blog' ); ?>">
                  
                  <div class="flex">
                  <label>
                    <input type="search" class="search_field_custom" placeholder="Insert Search Words…" value="" name="search" title="Search for:" />
                  </label>

                  <input type="submit" class="search_submit_custom" value="Search" />
                  </div>

                  <div class="flex">
                    <select name="yearnum">
                      <option value="false">Select year</option>

                      <?php 
                        foreach($years as $year) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';;

                        }
                      ?>
                    </select>
                    <select name="monthnum">
                      <option value="false">Select month</option>
                      
                      <?php 
                        foreach($months as $month => $month_value) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$month_value.'">'.$month.'</option>';;
                          
                        }
                      ?>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" class="search_submit_custom" value="Search" />
                  </div>
                </form>
```

Once I get the query I loop through the posts.

However in practice it seems to only let me search by the search field and the year, any combination with the month seems to fail and go to a 404, any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to divide this up into two parts. If you have a form that is causing a 404, I'd fix that first. It could be that one or more of the parameters are messing things up, a plugin is doing something funky, or maybe a server rule (such as htaccess) is getting in the way. Once you get the 404 to stop, I'd then get to the `get_posts` stuff.

Comment: Oh I figured it out basically monthnum is a reserved word for the params, I switched it to something else and it worked.